# Push value in one json to another json in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have 2 different JSON object

**JSON1**

```
 [
   {
     title: "Order Rule Violations",
     type: "FieldView",
     panel: "expanded",
     data: [      
       {
         label: "Rule Description",       
         type: "text",
       },
       {  
         label: "comments",       
         type: "inputarea",
       },
     ],
   },
 ]
```

**JSON2**

```
[
  {
    data: [
      {
        value: "00695",
      },
      {        
        value: " ",        
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I need to combine and get a result like

```
[
  {
    title: "Order Rule Violations",
    type: "FieldView",
    panel: "expanded",
    data: [
      {
        label: "Rule Description",       
        type: "text",
        value: "00695",
      },
      { 
        label: "comments",       
        type: "inputarea",
        value: " ",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Please advise how can I achieve this using Angular / Typescript

Comment: This isn't an angular specific question. It can be accomplished in either Javascript or Typescript, depending on what you're using?

Comment: I need in Typescript

Answer (score 0):

This shall for this case:

```
for(var i=0;i<JSON1[0].data.length;i++)
JSON1[0].data[i].value= JSON2[0].data[i].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use a nested [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to iterate over each array and then merge the two objects.

```js
const json1 = [{
  title: 'Order Rule Violations',
  type: 'FieldView',
  panel: 'expanded',
  data: [{
      label: 'Rule Description',
      type: 'text',
    },
    {
      label: 'comments',
      type: 'inputarea',
    },
  ],
}];

const json2 = {
  data: [{
      value: '00695',
    },
    {
      value: ' ',
    },
  ]
};

const json3 = json1.map(y => {
  y.data = y.data.map(
      (x, index) => Object.assign(x, json2.data[index])
    );
  return y; 
 });
  
console.log(json3);
```

Another solution is to use [Lodash's `_.merge` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I will try this too and use it appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I altered JSON2 a little bit like JSON2 = ["","","",....] and the code below
worked for me ,

```
var k=0;  
    for(var i=0; i<this.JSON1.length; i++){                  
                      for(var j=0; j<this.JSON1[i].data.length; j++){
                       console.log("j",j);
                        this.JSON1[i].data[j].value = this.JSON2[k];
                        k++;        
                      } 
                    }
```